# I cant make a paddle in python with the turtle module

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I cant find the problem, i have looked through the code several times.( i am a beginner)It doesnt make a paddle.

```
import turtle 

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("pong by ChunkyChungus")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0,)


wn.exitonclick()
```

Please help me with this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly does it do that it should not, and/or the reverse?

Comment: `.goto(-350, 0,)` is going to take the turtle way off of the visible screen.

Comment: didnt work ive made another game where i had this code, but now it doesnt work.

Comment: @jasonharper, the OP `setup()` a *width* of 800 so the x coordinates run from -400 to +400 so there isn't a problem with the turtle going off the visible screen.  (And the y coordinate will be in the middle of the screen.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'wn.tracer(0)' is what was blocking the turtle shape. The following code works for me. Notice that I've commented out 'wn.tracer(0)'.

```
import turtle 

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("pong by ChunkyChungus")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
# wn.tracer(0)

paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=5)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0,)

wn.exitonclick()
```